# How to push code on my local machine to GitHub in the main branch

Tags: git, github

I have created a Repository as the default main branch.

Step I tried to add to the repository:

1. git config --global init.befaultBranch main
2. git init -b main
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "commit to main branch"
5. git remote add origin '**my git url**'

Now I have stuck to push to the **origin**

I have tried `git push -u origin main` but it gave me an error as:

> ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'my git url'

How to push the code from my local machine to GitHub in the **main** branch?

Any help and pointing to the documentation will be appreciated.

I tried to pull first and there is also an error on doing that:

```
$ git pull origin main
```

> From `my git url`  * branch
> main       -> FETCH_HEAD fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Comment: it tells you to pull first before pushing.. do `git pull` then try `push`

Comment: or `git push -u origin main --force`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That only happens because your remote repository was initialized not empty, but with some files (`README.md` for instance)

That is why force pushing is a good option (in that case)

```
git push -f -u origin main
```

If you had created the repository empty, a regular push would have been enough.

Comment: yeah, it was created with the default README.md, so force push worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename your current branch to main.

```
git branch -M main
```

After that you can push code using new branch name **main**

```
git push -u origin main
```